# Is there a limit on maximum number of allowed AWS::Events::Rule in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are creating events while creating the AWS Stack using cloudformation.
However we are getting the following error while creating the events

AWS::Events::Rule - The requested resource exceeds the maximum number allowed.

Is there a limit for the max number of events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indeed seems that there is a limit as can be seen at [Cloudwatch rules and api requests limits](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/cloudwatch-events-increases-rules-and-api-requests-limits/)

> Number of Rules – Limit is now 100 rules per region per account (Previously 50 rules)